# Entity Framework Where() against a many to many without the collection populated

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

This is for a web app managing volunteers for political campaigns.

We have User.cs which represents a volunteer. They have a collection of Campaigns they are interested in volunteering for (which is a subset of all campaigns):

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Campaign> Campaigns { get; set; }
}
```

Each campaign has a collection of those users following it (i.e. it's a many to many between User and Campaign). Each Campaign also has a collection of Events, such as fundraisers. This is a 1 to many relationship:

```
public class Campaign : IOrganization
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<Event> Events { get; private set; }
    public ICollection<User> Followers { get; private set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public Campaign Campaign { get; private set; }
}
```

If I want to get all Events (not Campaigns, Events) that a user is following I can do it as follows:

```
var allEvents = context.Events.Where(e => user.Campaigns.Contains(e.Campaign)).ToListAsync();
```

This works great **if** user.Campaigns is populated. But if it's not populated, then it fails.

So here's the question - I could write the above query directly in SQL (no Entity Framework) where it does not require the user.Campaigns collection. I just reference the User_Campaign join table and use that to get the matching Events.

Is there a way to accomplish the same using Entity Framework? Because loading the user.Campaigns merely to run the select is a performance & memory hit that is unnecessary.

**Update:**

Ok, thanks to @SvyatoslavDanyliv I worked through this and got it working. Unfortunately, I worked through it with ChatGPT where it did all the real work and therefore I can't post that as an answer. But yes, this can be done.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of filtering by user.Campaigns, you could go by Id.
Something like

```
var allEvents = context.Events
    .Where(e => e.Campaign.Followers.Any(f => f.Id = user.Id))
    .ToListAsync();
```

Comment: Followers is also empty. That is a larger collection so it would be more expensive to do it that way. Thanks

Comment: @DavidThielen, what are tolking about? Just try correct query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv I did try it with those collections null - I got a null exception from deep inside EF.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thank you - based on what you said asked ChatGPT and it gave me the solution. If you write that up as an answer I'm happy to select it. I can't answer it myself as ChatGPT gave me the solution.

Comment: @DavidThielen There is nothing more to be answered here. ESG gave you a valid solution, not sure why you insist asking ChatGPT for something you asked here (why?) and got answered. In general you seem to totally misunderstand the difference between server side query (basically SQL) like in the answer and client side like yours. FYI, there are no "collections" and "objects" inside SQL query.

Comment: @IvanStoev Yes you're right except I ma server side - I'm writing a Blazor server app, not WASM. And the ESG answer threw a null exception - not sure why but ChatGPT gave me a different approach that works so all good.

Comment: @DavidThielen It doesn't matter what type of app is using EF Core for data access. "Server side" in EF Core context means database (SQL query/command) vs C# code. See [Client vs. Server Evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval) and [How Queries Work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/how-query-works) topics in the official docs. There is no way ESG query to generate NRE, in case you are not modifying it (of course it needs `await`, the same way as your OP example). It's not the only way to write such query, but it doesn't make it invalid...

Comment: @DavidThielen ... The main problem with your original query is that it performs filtering (`Where`) client side (C# code). Which not only requires client `user` object instance to have all navigation collection/references loaded, but also reads the whole table from database into in-memory objects, which is highly inefficient, even when "working". As you can see in the docs, it is the main reason client evaluation being disabled generally in EFC 3.0+.

Comment: @IvanStoev yes, I learned that working through the problem with ChatGPT. The problem is, we’re not allowed to post ChatGPT generated answers so I’ve not said this myself. Now that you’ve said it, I hope it’s ok to say ChatGPT also said it. (This limit on ChatGPT is a royal PITA.)